# Box behind text with multiline clip path

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create the css for the attached image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ozo.png). However I'm unsure how I would create a box behind the text which would include slanted corners. I've tried using skew and clip path. But the problem comes when the text goes on multiple lines like the attached image. Also the text goes a bit outside of the box which I believe where clip path comes into place.

```css
.tail{
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;

  span{
    &:after{
      content: '';
      background-color: rebeccapurple;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="tail">
  <span>Line 1 Text? L2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet un...</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Hi Volen! Welcome :) Can you include a picture of the current output you are getting for the image?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/provolkata/nc0k5m3s/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try background coloration like below:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.tail span {
  padding:0 30px 0 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(-60deg, #0000 20px, rebeccapurple 0);
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
          box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="tail">
  <span>Line 1 Text? <br /> L2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet un...</span>
</h1>
```